# How to send information from custom cells to a view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, custom-cell

Im currently trying to send some information from custom cells to the next view controller in Xcode 7 with Swift 2.

I can send information fine if it is from a label etc but i cannot do it from cells as I'm unable to get the specific cell the user tapped. I have tried to take information from tutortials on how to get the index path but always get an error.

[Layout of View Controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozQcQ.png)

[Code for main VC and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYCDi.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: your segue is connected with your cell?

Comment: Omg thank you !! It wasn't no, it was hooked up the the background. XD

Comment: Im such an idiot lmao

Comment: Not related, but consider to use **one** custom class rather than three arrays for the data source. Multiple arrays are very error-prone because you have to ensure that the number of items in all arrays are the same. And use always native Swift collection types rather than Foundation `NS(Mutable)...` objects. You throw away the crucial type information.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to create segue like `ViewController` to `ExpanView` Make sure
   not for `UITableViewCell` To `ExpanView`
2. your `tableView.allowsSelection = true` And set `tableView.delegate = self`
3. Implyment `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method of tableView like this way.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("exapanView", sender: indexPath)
   }
   ```
4. implement `prepareForSegue` method like this way

   ```
   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "exapanView" {
       let selectedIndexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
       let nameString = self.name.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row)
   }
   }
   ```